# Laravel 5.5 Collection Partial Grouping

Tags: php, collections, laravel-5.5

I need help on how to group the collection below by location and then by sizes:

```
[
    {
        "location_id": 1,
        "location_address": "Some address",
        "location_image": "https://some/image.url",
        "size_id": 1,
        "size_code": "S",
        "available_boxes": 3
    },
    {
        "location_id": 1,
        "location_address": "Some address",
        "location_image": "https://some/image.url",
        "size_id": 2,
        "size_code": "M",
        "available_boxes": 4
    },
    {
        "location_id": 1,
        "location_address": "Some address",
        "location_image": "https://some/image.url",
        "size_id": 3,
        "size_code": "L",
        "available_boxes": 5
    },
    {
        "location_id": 2,
        "location_address": "Some other address",
        "location_image": "https://some/other/image.url",
        "size_id": 4,
        "size_code": "XL",
        "available_boxes": 10
    }
]
```

Here is the expected result:

[image: expected result]

Really appreciate it, thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried writing anything ?

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to include your own efforts  (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: @GhostCat, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Might not be elegant, but this does the job:

```
$locations = $this->records->unique('location_id');
$transformed = [];

foreach ($locations as $location) {
    $sizes = $this->records->whereStrict('location_id', $location->location_id);
    $transformedSizes = [];

    foreach ($sizes as $size) {
        $transformedSizes[] = [
            'id' => $size->size_id,
            'code' => $size->size_code,
            'available_boxes' => $size->available_boxes
        ];
    };

    $transformed[] = array_merge(
        [
            'id' => $location->location_id,
            'address' => $location->location_address,
            'image' => $location->location_image
        ],
        [
            'sizes' => $transformedSizes
        ]
    );
}

return $transformed;
```